# Getting Sapi to say a string

Tags: c++, string, sapi

I have a program that asks a person to have the text they want to have translated into Al Bhed, which is just a cipher where the letters are moved around,and have the SAPI say it. the string translates fine, but this piece of code:

```
hr = pVoice->Speak(sTranslated, 0, NULL);
```

will not work, because it says "no suitable conversion function from 'std::string' to 'const WCHAR*' exists.
All I want is for the voice to say the translated string. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the `std::string` content, which uses type `char`, into a `std::wstring`, which uses type `wchar_t`. This is due to the fact that the `ISpVoice::Speak()` function requires that the first parameter be of type `LPCWSTR`, IOW a "const pointer to a wide character string". The following function may be of assistance to you.

```
inline std::wstring s2w(const std::string &s, const std::locale &loc = std::locale())
{
    typedef std::ctype<wchar_t> wchar_facet;
    std::wstring return_value;
    if (s.empty())
    {
        return return_value;
    }
    if (std::has_facet<wchar_facet>(loc))
    {
        std::vector<wchar_t> to(s.size() + 2, 0);
        std::vector<wchar_t>::pointer toPtr = &to[0];
        const wchar_facet &facet = std::use_facet<wchar_facet>(loc);
        if (0 != facet.widen(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.size(), toPtr))
        {
            return_value = to.data();
        }
    }
    return return_value;
}
```

Then change the line of code to the following.

```
hr = pVoice->Speak(s2w(sTranslated).c_str(), 0, NULL);
```

The `c_str()` method returns a pointer to a "C-string equivalent" of the `std::wstring` object.  IOW, it returns a pointer to a null-terminated wide string.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Remy Lebeau. You significantly improved my answer.